# using continue on a loop over a query with the group attribute breaks the loop

Tags: lucee

The goal is to use cfcontinue within a nested loop over a query that uses the group attribute.
The expected result is that the loop will continue with the next iteration after calling cfcontinue.
The actual result is that calling cfcontinue behaves like cfbreak. It will stop the inner loop completely and move on the the next iteration in the outer loop.

The situation is as follows:
I have a query result containing something like the following:

```
testQuery = queryNew( "id , LOJVal" , "numeric , varchar" ,
 { 
   id: [ 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 ] ,
   LOJVal: [ "val1" , "", "","val1" , "val2", "val3","val1" , "", "val3" ] 
 });
```

this query is a simplification of the result from a query like:

```
SELECT table.id, leftOuterJoinTable.LOJVal
FROM table
LEFT OUTER JOIN leftOuterJoinTable ON leftOuterJoinTable.id = table.id
```

where leftOuterJoinTable can contain multiple records for one record in table

when processing this query we want to loop over the records and group by id. We also want to validate the records, and if the record is not valid, we want to continue to the next. This looks something like the following:

```
<cfset var resultArr = []>
<cfset var outerLoopArr = [1,2,3]>
<cfset var outerLoopVal = "">
<cfloop array="#outerLoopArr#" item="outerLoopVal">
    <cfloop query="testQuery" group="id">
        <!--- this should iterate once per id --->
        <cfset var newVal = {}>
        <writeOutput>test</writeOutput>
        <cfif true><!--- record invalid --->
            <cfcontinue>
        </cfif>
        <!--- record valid --->
        <cfloop>
            <!--- do stuff with LOJVal --->
        </cfloop>
        <cfset arrayAppend(resultArr, newVal)>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

this code outputs the following:
`test test test`
yet the expected output is: `test test test test test test test test test`
for every iteration in the outer loop (3 iterations total) we have 3 iterations in the inner loop (one per group on id) so we'd expect 9 ''test''

When we remove the group attribute of the inner loop, the code behaves as expected: 3 * 9=27 * "test"

At first I thought maybe continue just triggers on the outer loop, so I added a label to the inner loop and continue like so:

```
<cfset var resultArr = []>
<cfset var outerLoopArr = [1,2,3]>
<cfset var outerLoopVal = "">
<cfloop array="#outerLoopArr#" item="outerLoopVal">
    <cfloop query="testQuery" group="id" label="innerloop">
        <!--- this should iterate once per id --->
        <cfset var newVal = {}>
        <writeOutput>test</writeOutput>
        <cfif true><!--- record invalid --->
            <cfcontinue innerloop>
        </cfif>
        <!--- record valid --->
        <cfloop>
            <!--- do stuff with LOJVal --->
        </cfloop>
        <cfset arrayAppend(resultArr, newVal)>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

as can be found in the docs https://docs.lucee.org/reference/tags/continue.html. But this doesn't seem to work eiter.

The only thing we can think of that could cause this is that continue will go to index + 1, but that doesnt exist because its grouped, so the next index would be + 3. And then the loop would be considered done because the index doesn't exist.

I haven't found any other information about this.

Comment: This seems to be a know issue in Lucee, see https://luceeserver.atlassian.net/browse/LDEV-1882

Comment: Why do you need `continue`? Seems like wrapping the appropriate in a `cfif` (with no cfelse) would achieve the same result?

Comment: thanks @AndreasRu and @SOS. Given that this is most likely not going to be solved I decided to use cfif, but in my opinion this gives some uglier code. Probably should've specified more but there are multiple checks for validating a record, and I don't want to do any checks after a previous one has been found false. So now I had to add an extra check in every validation check like `<cfif valid eq true AND currentCheck eq true>`

Comment: @robert - Yeah, do you really need multiple flags though? Couldn't you just check the valid flag and if it's true, do the next validation, and so on ... `<cfif valid> ... do 1st check... set valid = false if fails </cfif><cfif valid> ... do 2nd check...</cfif> ... etc... `? (Nothing to do with the issue but you could also drop the "eq true" if the values are boolean and just write `<cfif valid>`